# Why work-manager not use JobScheduler for 21 API

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I read about work-manager and its documentation says that it uses  JobScheduler on devices with API 23+ and Uses a combination of BroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager on devices with API 14-22 while JobScheduler is available from 21 API. So why its not using the JobScheduler from 21 API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this WorkManager issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125918746):

> We only use JobScheduler starting at API 23, because of bugs in JobScheduler in API 21 & 22.

As JobScheduler is a framework API, fixes are not able to be backported to previous versions of Android, leaving older versions, in this case API 21 and 22 devices, with a JobScheduler version that is unsuitable to build upon.